# sqlite command with multi primarykey?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, primary-key

This is my code:

```
private static final String CREATE_VISIT_TABLE =
    " create table " + VISIT_TABLE +
    " (tripdayid integer REFERENCES TripDay(_id)," +
    " poiid integer REFERENCES POI(_id)," +
    " arrival_time text not null," +
    " start_time text not null," +
    " visiting_duration text not null," +
    " leaving_time text not null,"
    " PRIMARY KEY (tripdayid, poiid));";
```

...but it returns an error, at the end of line:

> "Syntax error on token "" PRIMARY KEY (tripdayid, poiid));"", delete this token"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that the syntax error isn't coming from SQLite but from your compiler, you're missing a `+`:

```
" leaving_time text not null," // Missing + right here.
" PRIMARY KEY (tripdayid, poiid));";
```

Your compiler sees something like this:

```
"..." "..."
```

and doesn't know what to do about it, the double quotes in the error message:

```
"Syntax error on token "" PRIMARY KEY (tripdayid, poiid));""
                        ^                                 ^
                        |------ these ones ---------------|
```

are the give away.

Also, that PRIMARY KEY syntax is [allowed in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

Comment: and how about this one         private static final String CREATE_VISIT_TABLE =
     " create table " + VISIT_TABLE +
     " (_id integer autoincrement," +
     " tripdayid integer REFERENCES TripDay(_id)," +
     " poiid integer REFERENCES POI(_id)," +
     " arrival_time text not null," +
     " start_time text not null," +
     " visiting_duration text not null," +
     " leaving_time text not null,"+
     " PRIMARY KEY (_id, tripdayid));";

Comment: It say --> 08-09 11:28:25.380: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14339): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "autoincrement": syntax error:  create table Visit (_id integer autoincrement, tripdayid integer REFERENCES TripDay(_id), poiid integer REFERENCES POI(_id), arrival_time text not null, start_time text not null, visiting_duration text not null, leaving_time text not null, PRIMARY KEY (_id, tripdayid));

Comment: @android: I don't think SQLite likes [autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) except when it is combined with the primary key as in `col INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`. If you need a unique row identifier and a composite primary key, then you can use [`ROWID`](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).